# Using IN vs. EXISTS with Subquery- SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to retrieve data from QPS_Bonus_Tier table when certain criteria are met in QPS_Bonus table.  The Select statement in the subquery works and retrieves the desired rows, but I get the error 
*Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.*
when I try to run the Update query.

How should I structure this query? Thank you in advance. I am running SQL Server.  SID is the identity column of the table I am trying to update.

```
Update QPS_Bonus
SET QPS_Bonus.BonusRate=T.BonusRate
from QPS_Bonus B, QPS_Bonus_Tier T 
where B.SID IN
    (
        Select MAX(T.ProductionLevel) as ProdLevel, B.SID 

        from QPS_Bonus B
        INNER JOIN
        QPS_Bonus_Tier T on T.ProductionLevel <=B.Production 
        GROUP BY B.SID )
```

The MAX(ProductionLevel) is there because there is a range of Production values for each tier, e.g. 1.2-1.39 all are Tier 2, and 1.4-1.59 are all Tier 3.  These ranges need to be editable so I am not able to hard code them.  That is the reason for the separate QPS_Bonus_Tier table.

Comment: Looks like you just need to take out MAX(T.ProductionLevel).   Why is it in there anyway?

Comment: you return two columns with your subquery, but you are only allowed to return one!

Comment: The rhinocers way is to add another subqery `..where B.SID IN( select ProdLevel FROM(your subquery))`

Comment: Thank you, I tried this, and I am getting a syntax error at the )  whether I close the subquery with one or two parenthesis. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you should only return one column when using a subquery inside `IN`. As far as i see, you don't need that *ProdLevel*.
I think this gives you the desired output:

```
Update QPS_Bonus
SET QPS_Bonus.BonusRate=T.BonusRate
from QPS_Bonus B, QPS_Bonus_Tier T 
where B.SID IN
    (
        Select B.SID 

        from QPS_Bonus B
        INNER JOIN
        QPS_Bonus_Tier T on T.ProductionLevel <=B.Production 
        GROUP BY B.SID )
```

Comment: I ran the query as given above, without the ProdLevel, and again the subquery selects the appropriate rows, but instead of getting the error "Only one expression can be specified" I get Command completed/ 283 rows affected.  But no rows are updated.  As stated in my edited question, I need to join to or match the Max ProdLevel, as I want to return the single highest tier that matches the given production.

Comment: Well, there are affected rows, so you **did** update some rows. As far as i understand your concern with the `MAX(Prodlevel)`, you could use `ORDER BY Prodlevel` and add a `TOP 1`.